# RangeError after successfully stored data in MongoDB through node and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having two collections in MongoDB. hosts and places. Every host may own one or many places.

In my UserSchema I have a field:

place: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Place' }]

I have a route /addhost where both a newPlace and a newHost object is created through mongoose Schemas.

I then push the newPlace into the newHost.place array field.

Everything gets stored in the database correctly.

```
        // Save newPlace into MongoDB
        newPlace
            .save()
            .then((place) => res.json(place))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));

        // Save place objectID into host field array
        newHost.place.push(newPlace);

        // Save newHost into MongoDB
        newHost
            .save()
            .then((host) => res.json(host))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

The problem is I'm getting this error in my node.js-server:

"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.split ()
    at get (C:\web-projects\sprentdev\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\get.js:9:22)
    at isBsonType (C:\web-projects\sprentdev\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\isBsonType.js:10:10)
    at clone (C:\web-projects\sprentdev\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:68:7)
    at cloneObject (C:\web-projects\sprentdev\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:114:17)
    at clone (C:\web-projects\sprentdev\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:53:16)
    at cloneObject (C:\web-projects\sprentdev\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:114:17)
    at clone (C:\web-projects\sprentdev\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:53:16)
    at cloneObject (C:\web-projects\sprentdev\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:114:17)
    at clone (C:\web-projects\sprentdev\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:53:16)
    at cloneObject (C:\web-projects\sprentdev\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:114:17)
    at clone (C:\web-projects\sprentdev\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:53:16)
    at cloneObject (C:\web-projects\sprentdev\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:114:17)
    at clone (C:\web-projects\sprentdev\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:53:16)
    at cloneObject (C:\web-projects\sprentdev\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:114:17)
    at clone (C:\web-projects\sprentdev\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\clone.js:53:16)"

And it keeps looping like that. I'm a newbie I guess this is a trivial case, sorry for my ignorance.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
newPlace.save().then( place => {
    newHost.place.push(place._id);
    newHost.save().then((host) => res.json(host)).catch((err) => 
        console.log(err));
}).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

You are trying to push full object that too the old one. the new doc created is place and you need to push _id of newly created place document in the newHost obeject.